# Using a function from a model in a controller/view in Laravel

Tags: sql, controller, laravel, laravel-4, models

I am trying to access data from a query that I have placed within a function in a model.  I am trying to call the function within a controller, and then send along that data to a view.  So far, I have been unsuccessful.  Here is the code:

Model: Fanartist.php

```
public function fan_likes() {
        $fan_likes = DB::table('fanartists')
                    ->join('artists', 'fanartists.fan_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                    ->where('fanartists.fan_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->select('artists.id', 'artists.stage_name', 'artists.city', 'artists.state', 'artists.image_path', 'artists.description');

           }
```

Controller: FansController.php

```
public function getHome() {
            return View::make('fans.home')
            ->with('fans', Fan::all())
            ->with('fanartists', Fanartist::fan_likes());

        }
```

View:

```
@foreach($fanartists as $fanartist)

{{$fanartist}}

@endforeach
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Non-static method Fanartist::fan_likes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

UPDATE:

New error.  I am returning the view, but now, trying to run this:

```
@foreach($fanartists as $fanartist)
                {{$fanartist->artists.id}}

            @endforeach
```

I get the error:

log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/app/storage/views/2ed7fc8952dab08cf4cb4f4e3d40d1ab:100

UPDATE 2:

running:

```
@foreach($fanartists as $fanartist)
<?php var_dump($fanartist); ?>          
            @endforeach
```

I get the following output:

```
NULL array(6) { [0]=> string(10) "artists.id" [1]=> string(18) "artists.stage_name" [2]=> string(12) "artists.city" [3]=> string(13) "artists.state" [4]=> string(18) "artists.image_path" [5]=> string(19) "artists.description" } bool(false) string(10) "fanartists" array(1) { [0]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause)#201 (3) { ["type"]=> string(5) "inner" ["table"]=> string(7) "artists" ["clauses"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["first"]=> string(17) "fanartists.fan_id" ["operator"]=> string(1) "=" ["second"]=> string(10) "artists.id" ["boolean"]=> string(3) "and" } } } } array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["type"]=> string(5) "Basic" ["column"]=> string(17) "fanartists.fan_id" ["operator"]=> string(1) "=" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" ["boolean"]=> string(3) "and" } } NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

Comment: Error states it all try dumping $fanartists, see what it contains ? Is it an object??

Comment: hmm, it won't run the page when I try:  <?php var_dump($fanartists); ?>

Comment: don't know what are you doing?? just try `<?print_r($fanartists);?>` in your view and comment everything else

Comment: WHen I run that, I get: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://crowdtest.dev:8888/fans/home. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: can you paste your code on paste.laravel.io

Comment: I updated again, I got the output for "$fanartist" in the foreach loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33046/discussion-between-trying-tobemyself-rahul-and-user1072337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fanartist::fan_likes()` is not supposed to be called statically, but if you want to call it statically then change your fan_likes function to static.
for your example

```
public static function fan_likes() {
    $fan_likes = DB::table('fanartists')
                ->join('artists', 'fanartists.fan_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                ->where('fanartists.fan_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->select('artists.id', 'artists.stage_name', 'artists.city', 'artists.state', 'artists.image_path', 'artists.description');
return $fan_likes;
       }
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting the error in the view:  [2013-07-07 18:17:30] log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/app/storage/views/2ed7fc8952dab08cf4cb4f4e3d40d1ab:99

Comment: Error is in view.Because $fanartists is null.In your fan_likes() function you are not returning anything

Comment: Ok, yes that was the issue.  I updated my question with a new error:  I can't access {{$fanartist->artists.id}} or any of the other columns...

Answer (score 0):

if you have a non-static function like this in your MyClass controller:

```
    public function my_func( ) {
            // do stuff
    return ( $stuff ) ;
}
```

then in your controller, you can call it with code like this:

```
$local_obj = MyClass::findOrFail( $myobj_id );
$rval = $local_obj->my_func();
```

if you want to call it from your view, I think you need to pass the object to the view similar to this:

```
$data['my_obj'] = $local_obj;
return View::make('view_name.show')->with('data',$data);
```

and then to use in the view use something like this:

```
{{{$data['my_obj']->my_func() }}}
```

(above is copied and edited from working code - apols if i've made a typo )