# Calling Model Function From Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new on laravel.

I have functions on my model php. I want to use them in controller and send to view.

This is my example function.

```
public function select()
    {
        $users = DB::table('garanti')->get();
    }
```

now I need to use this on controller and view.

In codeigniter I handle it like this:

```
$data['kategori'] = $this->model->select_s();        
$this->load->view('admin/kategori', $data);
```

Comment: here you will get the idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515014/2567813

Comment: Are you having problem with this? Did you tested it? It's not working? Do you have any error messages to show us?

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function select()
    {
       return DB::table('garanti')->get();
    }

}
```

You can use it in your controller:

```
$data['kategori'] = with(new Post)->select();        

return View::make('admin/kategori')->with('data', $data);
```

There are in fact other ways of doing this, but static functions are not really testable, so I wouldn't use them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good LIVE example about using MVC concept in Laravel. in this scenario the Controller is calling a function from the Model class then the Controller handle the view.Take a look.

http://runnable.com/UnFiFHVGrQh1AAA_/mvc-in-laravel-for-php